# Finding all possible combination **patterns** - as opposed to all possible combinations

Tags: combinatorics

I start off with trying to find the number of possible combinations for a 5x5 grid (25 spaces), where each space could be a color from 1-4 *(so 1, 2, 3, or 4)*

I do `4^25 = 1,125,899,906,842,624 different combinations`

However, now I'm trying to change the number of combinations to account for grids with the same number pattern, for example:

{ 1 1 1 1 1 }
{ 3 3 3 3 3 }
{ 4 4 2 2 3 }
{ 4 3 2 1 1 }
{ 2 2 1 2 3 }

```
1 is now 2, 2 is now 4, 3 is now 1, 4 is now 3
```

{ 2 2 2 2 2 }
{ 1 1 1 1 1 }
{ 3 3 4 4 1 }
{ 3 1 4 2 2 }
{ 4 4 2 4 1 }

I'm having trouble trying to come up with an equation I can use to solve this for a (x * y) grid where each space could be a color from 1 to (c).

Comment: It appears what you want, if my interpretation is correct, is $\sum _{n=1}^c \mathcal{S}_{x y}^{(n)}$, where $x$ and $y$ are the dimensions $c$ is the number of colors, and $\mathcal{S}_{x y}^{(n)}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind. Quick test generating reasonable sized instances and checking counts checks out, but I've not proofed it, so caveat emptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum _{n=1}^c \mathcal{S}_{x y}^{(n)}$ is what you're after, with $x, y, c$ the two dimensions and the number of colors. $\mathcal{S}_{x y}^{(n)}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.

This generalizes to arbitrary dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to split the count according to the number of different numbers used. There are $4$ grids using one number each, but they all yield the same pattern.

At the other extreme there are

$$4^{25}-\binom43\cdot3^{25}+\binom42\cdot2^{25}-\binom41\cdot1^{25}=4^{25}-4\cdot3^{25}+6\cdot2^{25}-4$$

grids that use all four numbers. The four numbers can be permuted in $4!=24$ different ways, so there are

$$\frac1{24}\left(4^{25}-4\cdot3^{25}+6\cdot2^{25}-4\right)$$

patterns.

Given two colors, say $a$ and $b$, we can fill them into the grid in $2^{25}-2$ ways (since we need to exclude the one-number grids). However, that counts each pattern twice, since we can interchange $a$ and $b$, so this case contributes $2^{24}-1$ patterns.

Similarly, three colors can be filled into the grid in

$$3^{25}-\binom32\cdot2^{25}+\binom31\cdot1^{25}=3^{25}-3\cdot2^{25}+3$$

ways, but the colors can be permuted in $3!=6$ ways, so the number of patterns is only

$$\frac16\left(3^{25}-3\cdot2^{25}+3\right)=\frac12\left(3^{24}-2^{25}+1\right)\;.$$

Comment: I think there's an extra layer of complication for example in the 3-colour case because you draw the 3 colours from the 4 possible colours. The number of 3-colour patterns is correct, but the presence of those in the full set of combinations in the question is actually 24 times that value.

Comment: @Joffan: I gave the number of ways to fill three **colors** into the grid, not three **numbers**. It doesn’t matter which three numbers are chosen for the three colors. However, whichever three it is, they can still be permuted in $3!$ ways, so each $3$-element **pattern** corresponds to $6$ ways of filling in three unspecified **colors**.

Comment: As I said, the number of patterns in your solution is correct. I was just thinking of the OP's desire to *"account for grids with the same number pattern"*. Each 3-colour pattern will occur 24 times in the $4^{25}$ combination set.

Comment: @Joffan: Ah, I see. I took it that the real goal was imply counting the patterns.

Comment: I think this undercounts - using it for a 3x3 with 4 colors, it arrives at 7770 patterns. There are 11051. Unless I'm missing something and/or misinterpreting the OP.

Comment: @HammyTheGreek: The analysis that I gave yields the result $11051$; $7770$ is merely the contribution of the patterns that use all four colors. You must add in the other three cases to complete the calculation.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Ah, my mistake. Thanks - matches the compact formula in my comment under op.

Answer (score 1):

Observation. Note that
$${25\brace 1} + {25\brace 2} + {25\brace 3} + {25\brace 4}
\\= 1 + 2^{24} -1 + \frac{1}{2}(3^{24}-2^{25}+1)
+ \frac{1}{24}(4^{25}-4\times3^{25}+6\times2^{25}-4).$$

Answer (score 0):

Assign four colours (a,b,c,d) to the values (1,2,3,4) - how many ways can this be done? $4!=24$ That is the number you need to divide by, for grids that use all four colours, and (I think) for grids that only use three colours. For grids with only one or two colours, the number of options reduces, because switching the unused colours doesn't make any difference. So for example with monochrome grids, instead of $4!=24$ options there are only $\frac{4!}{6}=4$ options (of course). For two-colour grids, there are $\frac{4!}{2}=12$ options to divide out.

Comment: I was thinking this too, but thought that would be 24 ways.  And $4^{25}$ can't be divided by 24.  Is that wrong?

Comment: Hmm yeah.  This is probably because of the grids that don't use all four colours. More effort required...